# Подписать приложение

Tags: ios, signature, xcode7

Как подписать приложение для *Enterprise* релиза и для тестирования в *XCODE7*, под *iOS9*?

В Apple портале - несколкьо каких-то сертификатов, провижн профайлов.

Какой из них и как установить, чтобы можно было подписать ?

Где в *XCODE 7* настройки подписи приложения и как они должны быть настроены, чтобы подписать сначала сертификатом для тестирование, а потом энтерпрайз ?

*UDID* девайса добавил на портале.

Comment: какая каша...во первых это два абсолютно разных вопроса: профайл для тестирования и enterprise distribution. можно как то разбить на два?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, спасибо за отклик. Да, конечно надо разбить на ряд вопросов.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, подскажите, правильно ли я понимаю, что если подписать приложение Enterprise лицензией, тогда можно будет обойтись без подписывания приложения специально для тестирование, ибо и так можно будет поставить на все девайсы ?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, Вы не подскажите нужно ли как-то добавлять девайсы для распостранения In-House? Или же просто подписать их Ентерпрайз и скидывать своим сотрудникам?

Comment: последний раз имел дело с enterprise несколько лет назад. насколько я помню, если приложение подписать enterprise его можно запускать на любых девайсах.

Comment: давайте вот как сделаем. есть документация насчет того, как это делать. вы попробуйте, а если что то не получится, тогда приходите с вопросами. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html